# C# - WebRequest.GetResponce(): The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, encoding, webrequest

i'm having a problem with this simple code which sends a request using provided url and reads html from responce. Looks like it's something with encoding of cyrillic symbols after ?q=, but i can't see why (url was actually obtained from browser address bar, not generated or anything else).

```
url =
    "http://www.avito.ru/nizhniy_novgorod/kvartiry/sdam/na_dlitelnyy_srok?q=%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0+%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0+10%D0%BA1";
string html = "";
try
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Timeout = 100000;

    using (WebResponse responce = request.GetResponse())
    {
        Stream stream = responce.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        html = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Error occures in GetResponce() method. The message is:

```
The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should cast your request and response to HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse, respectively.

```
var url = "http://www.avito.ru/nizhniy_novgorod/kvartiry/sdam/na_dlitelnyy_srok?q=%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0+%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0+10%D0%BA1";
        string html = "";
        try
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(uri);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Timeout = 100000;


            using (HttpWebResponse responce = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                Stream stream = responce.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(html);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

Also, It seems that the url http://www.avito.ru/nizhniy_novgorod/kvartiry/sdam/na_dlitelnyy_srok?q=%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0+%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0+10%D0%BA1 is invalid.

Using Fiddler, the url returns a 404 error.